# convertir formato de fecha Orale

Tags: oracle, date

Estoy teniendo un gran lío porque en una tabla tengo una columna de fecha, la cual tiene dos tipos de registros.. fecha con formato DD/MM/YY y con formato DD/MON/RR

El problema es el siguiente, quiero convertir/actualizar los registros con formato DD/MON/RR hacia DD/MM/YY, he intentado con

to_date(fecha,'DD/MM/YY') y to_char(to_date(fecha,'DD/MON/RR'),'DD/MM/YY')

Y obtengo errores como

> ORA-01843: mes no válido
>   01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"

o este

> ORA-01858: se ha encontrado un carácter no numérico donde se esperaba
>   uno numérico

Alguna sugerencia para poder cambiar el formato hacia DD/MM/YY a todos los registros???

Comment: Podrias mostrar que tipo de sentencias probaste? porque lo que hiciste esta correcto, pero no para todos los registros ;), debes segmentar la tabla para solo convertir los registros que no cumplen eso. Un ejemplo tambien estaria bien

Comment: Puede pegar unos cuantos registros, digamos 10, a modo de ejemplo?

Answer (score 1):

### En Oracle una columna con tipo de dato DATE en sí misma NO tiene formato.

Por lo tanto es **IMPOSIBLE** que una columna de tipo DATE tenga 2 (dos) formatos.

El formato de visualización lo da la herramienta o cliente que utilice para "ver" el valor de esa columna.
Principalmente el formato está regido por la variable de ambiente NLS_LANG que tenga configurada en el sistema operacional al momento de ejecutar la herramienta o cliente (SQL*Plus, SQL-Developer, TOAD, PLSQL-Developer, SQLTools, o cualquier otra).

La única manera es que, por una decisión de diseño **desafortunada**, la columna sea de tipo VARCHAR2.

Y por lo tanto el sistema de información o el aplicativo que usa esa columna no está usando la función **TO_CHAR** para garantizar que el string de fecha se guarde en un formato consistente.

Puede consultar el tipo de dato de la columna en cuestión usando la vista ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.

La operación que está intentando aplicar presenta errores porque aquellos registros que tengan una fecha con nombre de mes, pues depende de cuál idioma usaron para los meses y del idioma que tenga su herramienta.

Dado que la columna es de tipo VARCHAR2, **nunca** debe usar una función **TO_DATE** para realizar una asignación.
Siempre debe usar la función **TO_CHAR**, preferiblemente incluyendo el tercer parámetro que define el idioma.